# cdk SageMaker.CfnModel outputs empty containers property when passed model package arn

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, amazon-sagemaker

When I try to pass a model package to cdk CfnModel the template output has an empty dictionary. Then input checks require an array of objects, however whatever I pass does not end up in the template output. What is the issue here?

Given the input below, I am expecting an output with the containers property set to  {"ModelPackageName": model_package_arn}, but it is an array with an empty dictionary (see below).

Input

```
class Model(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)
        model_package_arn = 'arn:aws:sagemaker:us-east-2:{ACCOUNT}:model-package/xgboost-abalone2023-01-30-15-28-52/1'
        model = sagemaker.CfnModel(
                        self,
                        "MLInference",
                        execution_role_arn=my_role,
                        model_name="my-model",
                        containers=[{"ModelPackageName": model_package_arn}] #<--- Passing an array of dictionary as required
```

Output:

```
"Resources": {
  "MLInference": {
   "Type": "AWS::SageMaker::Model",
   "Properties": {
    "ExecutionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::243788878595:role/service-role/A2ISageMaker-ExecutionRole-20221116T114907",
    "Containers": [
        {} #<----------- this should be {"ModelPackageName": model_package_arn}] from the cdk stack
    ],
    "ModelName": "my-model7"
   },
   "Metadata": {
    "aws:cdk:path": "AdverseEventsStack/MLInference"
   }
  }}
```

Answer (score 0):

the containers attribute requires a sagemaker.CfnModel.ContainerDefinitionProperty

The correct python syntax looks like this

```
containers=[sagemaker.CfnModel.ContainerDefinitionProperty(
                                        model_package_name=model_package_arn
                                    )]
```